# How to select specific column to import using BCP whithout configuration file?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm using BCP command to import, in SQL Server 2005, through of a configuration file. So:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP database.dbo.table in d:\folder\foo.csv -f d:\folder\configuration.xml -c -t, -T -F 2 '
```

I want to import certain columns without having to use the configuration file 'configuration.xml'.

Comment: Does your bcp command already work correctly? And why do you not want to use a format file? They are [required](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190393.aspx#WhenFFrequired) in several scenarios and there is no reason to avoid them. If you can explain why you do not want to use one then someone may have a suggestion.

Comment: @Pondlife, thanks for your comment. I don't want use a format file because of I don´t want to depend of external file since only of a command.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you consider format files to be an issue: every solution has some dependencies, and you're already depending on the .csv files being there, xp_cmdshell being enabled, correct permissions being set on the folders etc. It's normal to have a 'library' of bcp format files that you use for different bulk operations (and keeping them under source control is a good idea). If you really want to avoid it you could write your own scripts to import the data or perhaps use an SSIS package, but just using a format file seems like the easiest thing.

Comment: Thank you @Pondlife I'm going to consider.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try by query...

it results the data.... and you pass that to your table...

```
INSERT INTO tablename
    SELECT * FROM
    OPENROWSET ('MSDASQL', 'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DBQ=D:\sam;', 'SELECT name,id from sam.csv');
```

Comment: Queryout is to export, isn't it? I want to import. Thanks!

Comment: no problem! I have a set of csv files. Some files have header and other no. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried with drivers like 'MSDASQL', but when the file is too big, it doesn't charge it. So that I prefer use BCP